# What webcams are just working with Ubuntu 9.10 - without requiring additional drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-9.10, webcam

I'm looking for webcams that can work on the new Ubuntu 9.10 without requiring any driver installation.

Please remind that Ubuntu 9.10 dropped support for V4L1 and supports only V4L2. So if your webcam worked with previous Ubuntu versions it may not work anymore with the new one.

Please respond only with models that you know that are just working.

So far I only identified these models:

- [Logitech Webcam C200](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)
- [Trust SpaceCam 120 (120 SpaceC@m)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams)
- [Trust SpotLight Webcam Pro](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams)

Don't bother adding build-in webcams here.

Note, I'm aware about the comprehensive list from http://linux-uvc.berlios.de but this list does not guarantee that these cams will just-work under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, so I hope someone finds this useful:

I think you answered your own question.  You can always buy one and take it back if it doesn't work...

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1342189- The Logitech should work
- according to a forum post, the SpaceCam 120 needed `libvideo-ivtv-perl` to work on old versions of Ubuntu
- Trust SpotLight Webcam Pro seems to work on Ubuntu (see next bullet point)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams- Webcams that work with Skype on Ubuntu

Generally, webcams that work on Linux should work out of the box on Ubuntu because things like that are generally included in the kernel.